# No module named simple error in Django

Tags: django, virtualenv, django-urls, importerror

I am working on a Django Bookmarks project and it requires you to call the `simple.py` from `django.views.generic`. But when I ran my server I got an import error that their was no module named `simple`. I looked in the folder and it was not there. I looked up some information on the issue. I read that in the newer version through git hub it does not have the file. I cannot figure out how to fix it. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import os
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django_bookmarks.bookmarks.views import *
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template


site_media = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'site_media'
    )

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', main_page),
    (r'^user/(\w+)/$', user_page),
    (r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    (r'^logout/$', logout_page),
    (r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
     {'document_root': site_media}),
    (r'^register/$', register_page),
    (r'^register/success/$', direct_to_template,
     {'template': 'registration/register_success.html'}),

    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'django_bookmarks.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^django_bookmarks/', include('django_bookmarks.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: Did you find out if the `simple` module was renamed or removed completely?

Comment: It was never there in the first place. My roommate had the file on hers because she has an earlier version of Django. I had her send it to me and I placed it in the folder but it is still not working.

Answer (score 2):

It seems function based views have been deprecated in Django 1.3 (and may have been removed in the latest dev)
You should then replace them with the class-based views provided in Django 1.4

[Deprecated function-based generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/)
[Class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/)

You might be interested in the TemplateView.

Comment: So if I use class based views, then in my views.py I would use a class instead of a function?

Comment: Do I have to convert all of my pages/functions to classes or just the one I wanted to use for simple?

Answer (score 0):

`django.views.generic.simple` was deprecated and doesn't exist beyond django 1.4. Is there a specific reason you are using a development branch of django and not the latest stable version (1.4.2)?

I would recommend either using django 1.4.2 (which has `django.views.generic.simple` or use `render` (`from django.shortcuts import render`) instead of `direct_to_template`.

Comment: also i am using the developmental version for class....we are using 1.3.4  but I have a mac and I had to download it through git hub and I had to get the latest version

Comment: I believe `render` performs the same function as `direct_to_template`. You can simply change to django 1.4.2 from the development branch by running `git checkout 1.4.2`.

Comment: But we are using the developmental version for class.. :/